# How to handle 100vh in flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I have a page I am trying to render a page via WebView in Flutter.

The page has a height of 100 vh (in CSS) and when attempting to render this page in my app, the app bar covers up the upper portion of the page. I believe this is due to the page having 100vh.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to handle such a case and force the page to render at a smaller height so that the app bar does not cover up the top part of the page.

EDIT: To be clear, this is someone else's webpage, I cannot edit their css.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the calc() method. If you know the height of the app bar, you can set the height as following:

Lets assume the height of the app bar is 65px for now. Then you would use the following line of css:

```
.appbody{
    height: calc(100vh - 65px);
    margin-top: 65px; /* Clear the space for the app bar above */
}
```

I would recommend to use the min-height property if possible. When your app screen gets larger, the size can increase with the length of the content:

```
.appbody{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 65px);
    margin-top: 65px; /* Clear the space for the app bar above */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but this is someone else's website so I cannot edit their CSS code.